# Disable LeakCanary for given tests / test classes

Tags: android, leakcanary

I have added LeakCanary2 to instrument test by simply adding it to the gradle file.

It works great but it enables LeakCanary for all my tests, which is time consuming. Is there a way that I can only enable LeakCanary for a small set of tests / test classes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FailAnnotatedTestOnLeakRunListener](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/api/leakcanary-android-instrumentation/leakcanary/-fail-annotated-test-on-leak-run-listener/) instead of `FailTestOnLeakRunListener`:

> A JUnit RunListener extending FailTestOnLeakRunListener to detecting memory leaks in Android instrumentation tests only when the @FailTestOnLeak annotation is used.

Comment: But even it doesn't fail, it still runs, right? My goal is to stop the tests from running to save time.

Comment: It will only run for tests annotated with @FailTestOnLeak . But yes, when it runs, well, it runs.

Comment: Do you mean if I use FailAnnotatedTestOnLeakRunListener, the tests without @FailTestOnLeak will not run? It does not appear to be the case for me. Is it because I also have LeakCanary in debugImplementation()?  I work on open-source and will happily show you the code if you are interested.

Comment: > Do you mean if I use FailAnnotatedTestOnLeakRunListener, the tests without @ FailTestOnLeak will not run?

the tests without @ FailTestOnLeak should run, but without LeakCanary.

You can always file an issue on the LeakCanary project.